# WCS AJAX refresh using dojo and controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo, websphere-commerce, wcs

I am working on Aurora Store, I have created a refresh controller to refresh an area.

But the controller works only first time, means when the page loaded first time and thebutton is clicked on which I have written the refresh controller only then area gets refresh after that area doesn't get refreshed,  what am I missing?

code for reference:

**Sample Application for refreshing a section of a page with person details on click of a button**

**1.  Defined the context in a JavaScript file. The context will handle and allow refreshing the area, Set controller's URL in a jsp file**

```
 wc.render.declareContext("MyAreaContext",null,""),
  SBControllersDeclarationJS.setControllerURL('CustomController','<c:out value="${AjaxCustomInformationViewURL}"/>');
```

**2. Put this div before the area which needs to be refreshed**

```
  <div dojotype="wc.widget.RefreshArea" widgetid="RefreshAreaDisplay" 
                controllerid="CustomController" id="RefreshCustomAreaDisplay" role="wairole:region" 
                waistate:live="polite" waistate:atomic="false" waistate:relevant="all">
```

within this div following is the content

```
  ${person.email1}

        ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}

        ${person.addressLine[0]}

        ${person.country}
                   </div>
```

**3.  Event(button click)  which triggers update Context**

```
<a role="button"
                       id="WC_Custom_links_1" tabindex="0"
                       href="JavaScript:CustomHelper.updateInfo();      wc.render.updateContext('CustomAreaContext');">
```

Function "updateInfo" is working fine each time clicked but refresh is not working after first time.

**4. Struts-config-ext.xml**

```
 <forward className="com.ibm.commerce.struts.ECActionForward" name="CurrentCustomView/47401" path="/ShoppingArea/CustomInfo.jsp"/>
```

**5.URL construction**

```
 <wcf:url var="AjaxCustomInformationViewURL" value="CurrentCustomView" type="Ajax">
                  <wcf:param name="langId" value="${langId}" />                        
                  <wcf:param name="storeId" value="${WCParam.storeId}" />
                <wcf:param name="catalogId" value="${WCParam.catalogId}" />
               <wcf:param name="orderId" value="${currentOrderId}" />
           </wcf:url>
```

**6. Controller definition : URL to be called, here kept it as  null because this will be updated  in the client jsp**

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
                wc.render.declareRefreshController({
                id: "CustomController",
               renderContext: wc.render.getContextById("CustomAreaContext"),
               url: "",
             formId: ""
             ,modelChangedHandler: function(message, widget) {

               var controller = this;
                var renderContext = this.renderContext;
                widget.refresh(renderContext.properties);
              cursor_clear();  


             }
           ,renderContextChangedHandler: function(message, widget) {

          var controller = this;
          var renderContext = this.renderContext;
          widget.refresh(renderContext.properties);
           cursor_clear();  

         }
       ,postRefreshHandler: function(widget) {
        var controller = this;
        var renderContext = this.renderContext;
        cursor_clear();

       }
      });
   </script>
```

**7. CustomInfo.jsp**

```
  <wcf:rest var="person" url="store/{storeId}/person/@self"
            scope="request">
            <wcf:var name="storeId" value="${WCParam.storeId}" encode="true" />
</wcf:rest>

        ${person.email1}

        ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I was parsing the widget with wrong name.

Comment: Can you clarify on what parsing issue was it since I have a similar issue?

Comment: @cnu sorry didn't get your question, my issue was that i mistyped the widget name. You just need to check that all the ids(wherever) are used and names are what are intended.